# Moving to Republic of Ireland with a UK re-entry ban

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, south-africa, visa-bans

The background is:

- I am a UK citizen and my wife is a South African citizen
- My wife has a ban from the UK for 12 months (due to
  an overstayed visa, mistakes were made on our end with the dates)
- I am currently in the process of acquiring my Irish passport (Irish grandparents)

We plan on moving to Cork (In Ireland) for a year until her re-entry ban is up and we can continue our lives in the UK. The initial idea was that my wife can travel to Cork without a visa (stamp on entry?) and then apply for a right to work through my Irish passport. Then we can both stay and work in Ireland for the foreseeable future.

Will her re-entry ban to the UK have an effect on any of this? I wouldn't have thought twice about it usually, but I read something online stating that the UK re-entry ban could have an effect on anyone traveling to Ireland (let alone someone wanting to move there)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that her entry ban would be applicable to an application for a settlement visa? My understanding is that entry bans do not apply to family member visas, unless the applicant has *"aggravating circumstances, such as absconding, not meeting temporary admission/reporting restrictions or bail conditions, using an assumed identity or multiple identities, switching nationality, making frivolous applications or not complying with the re-documentation process"*. Apologies if you have already sought legal advice over this, but if you haven't done so then you should.

Comment: Also, this question might be a better fit for expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you so much dude. We are contacting immigration lawyers now, that is a huge ray of hope in this bad situation.

Comment: You would be better situated if you were _not_ a citizen of Ireland; then you would have a freedom-of-movement right to have your wife join you in Ireland. But this doesn't automatically apply when your right to reside in Ireland comes from being a citizen there.

Comment: @Michael Yes, also what Henning said. Your wife has a right, as your spouse, to accompany you or reunite with you in any EU nation (other than your own). Either by presenting evidence at the border, or through a quick visa application. Ireland does often deny visas to people denied UK visas, but they cannot do this in your case. Incidentally, what I quoted is from the Immigration Rules. They are not easy to read, but the first paragraph lays out the exemption from most refusal rules for family members. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Comment: Irish citizens can move their spouses to the UK under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations 2016 even if the spouse has a ban under the Immigration Rules. However, if you are *also* a British citizen, this may be unavailable to you.  I think the applicability of the Regulations to dual citizens has changed, though, so you may want to look into it further.  In any event, the question is off topic here; it belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @MJeffryes if the OP is Irish, though, then Ireland isn't an "EU nation other than his own," is it?

Comment: @phoog Yes that's true, but OP hasn't made it clear where in the process of acquiring an Irish passport he is. Since he has an Irish grandparent, he is entitled to Irish citizenship, but he wasn't born an Irish citizen, so he may not yet have completed the citizenship process. Regardless, I think the best thing for OP to do at this point is seek legal advice, since seemingly their desire is to live in the UK.

Comment: @MJeffryes agreed.  One possible route, though time may be running out owing to Brexit, would be to try the Surinder Singh route after some time in Cork, but it might be necessary to *avoid* obtaining Irish citizenship for this to work.